# Extracting specific line of text with grep for use in conky

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, conky, quod-libet

I'm trying to extract the directory of the current playing song in Quodlibet for use in attempting to display album artwork in conky.

In QL's *current* file `~/.quodlibet/current` there is a line that gives you the full path of the currently playing song, but I only need the directory. Is there a way I can ignore the last part of the path with grep?

For example if I had a file called `/music/album/03-song.ogg`, I'd only want grep to output everything before the `0` (or `1/2/3/4` for longer albums).

I've no idea if I can use this for what I need it for, but it would still be useful to know for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

If the `current` file contains a valid path to a file, simply get its directory name:

```
dirname $(< ~/.quodlibet/current)
```

The `$(< …)` will read a file and substitute its contents [as if it was `cat`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst#specialities).

You don't actually want to parse the file or use any regular expressions. This is likely to break if the directory name contains a "0", for example. The only reliable source of information for determining the directory is the last slash, and `dirname` handles just that anyway.

Comment: This is a more elegant solution, but while regular expressions can easily break (they aren't too user-friendly), you can parse directories effectively with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by piping your `grep` output to `sed` and using regular expressions to extract the info you want.

You can read up on `sed` and its regular expression syntax from its manual page.

Comment: I'd like to know what's wrong with this answer from whomever down-voted it.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted you, but if you're going to use sed anyway, why bother with a grep in the first place?  I'd say it was unnecessary effort.

Comment: @tink Putting it in multiple stages makes the regular expressions you have to write simpler, because you're breaking the problem down into simpler parts. You *can* rewrite it with a single regex, but that can easily make it very unwieldy. I've done both, and I prefer piping.

Comment: You can write it in multiple stages without involving `grep`. `grep 'whatever' ~/.quodlibet/current | sed 'whatever2'` is equivalent to `sed '/whatever/!d; whatever2' ~/.quodlibet/current`. You can string any number of expressions within `sed` and it will be aesthetically equivalent to piping, but (depending on what you're doing) more efficient.

Comment: @kine Good point, though for many tasks it would be a negligible difference in efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Just because I like sed :) ... love @slhck's brilliant solution!

```
$ echo /music/album/03-song.ogg| sed -r 's@^(.+)/.+$@\1@'
/music/album
```

Answer (score 0):

```
quodlibet --print-playing "<~dirname>"
```